# Close an app by showing prompt message

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

i want to close my currently working app when i press the exit button by showing some prompt message. i worked with window.close(). it is not working me properly. can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The question take two possibilities:

1) You want to exit the App by pressing a button in the App (SoftButton). But before the exit, you want to prompt a message.

OR

2) You want to show a prompt message when the user press the phone's exit physical button (HardButton). . But before the exit, you want to prompt a message.

Sencha-Touch Apps are typically JavaScript WebApps running in the phone's native browser.

In both cases, you want to know when the App is effectively closing so you prompt your message. Well, your only way in Javascript to detect that kind of stuff are `onunload` & `onbeforeunload` events.

Unfortunately those events are also fired when you leave over a link or a browsers back button.

See : [javascript detect close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)